# Underscore should not force mathmode in macro

Tags: macros, xetex, color, arabic

When trying to color words in arabic (transliteration), LaTeX wants me to be in mathmode (`Missing $ inserted.`), as there is an underscore in the transliteration. This is of course completely wrong as it is not math rather than `arabxetex`’s convention for some arabic letters.

The problem only occurs if I try to color it using a macro, the version using the `\color` command directly works without any problems. However, to me the two are seemingly identical, yet to LaTeX they obviously are not.

If I force the following code (ignoring all errors), I get this output:
[image: Forced Code]

The first line is “Try No. 1” and the second one “Try No. 2” and how it should actually look. I suspect the problem might lie in my macro but I fail to see where the error is.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}

\usepackage{arabxetex}
\SetTranslitConvention{dmg}

\newcommand*{\place}[1]{{\color{cyan} #1}}

\begin{document}

\place{\textarab[trans]{\UC ya_trib}}% Try No. 1
{\color{cyan} \textarab[trans]{\UC ya_trib}}% Try No. 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `underscore` package.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there a reason why you decided not to type in unicode?

Comment: I actually played with the idea, but in the end it came down to convenience (and also the reasons stated in the [ArabXeTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/arabxetex/arabxetex.pdf) Section 2.1), above all not having to deal with a bidirectional input file. And I am actually not 100% familiar with the transliteration, so I would have to look some things up, which is now dealt with automatically: If I see that the arabic is correct, I simply switch the `trans` option on and I have the correct output. Again, convenience ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\textarab` command changes internally the category code of `_`, so that it's not any more the subscript character for math formulas, but only in the argument of `\textarab`. However, this change is not any more possible if the argument has already been read (in this case as argument to `\place`).

You have two strategies available.

### Strategy 1

```
\begin{document}
\catcode`_=12
```

If you have little or no math in your document it is the simplest one; for an occasional subscript in math you can use `\sb` instead of `_`.

### Strategy 2

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\place}{{\color{cyan}\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}}
```

Here `\place` will make XeTeX reread the argument so that the change in the category code is performed correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected something catcode-related but I actually do not know anything about it. This worked.